# How to update database without explicitly declaring the engine and session in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**Context**

Using the pocoo.org Flask tutorial [(link)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial) as my starting point, I'm trying to work with an external SQL database instead of sqlite3.  The configuration and model documentation overview on pocoo [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/) and [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/) helped me establish the connection, and the queried data is rendering in my app, which is good.

**What's not working**

The issue is that when I update a record via the update view, it doesn't update the database on submit.  Instead, the page request loads without throwing any errors while still representing the the data in its former state.

**What I've tried so far**

I've looked for a solution in the documentation, Google, and stackoverflow archives, but as far as I can tell at this point, these assume that the app is connecting to the database via a declared session bound to an engine.  Pocoo's tutorial, on the other hand, doesn't explicitly declare the session or bind to an engine; instead, it registers a db.py file, which initializes the database, with the application factory.  The connection is configured with the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI configuration key, and the sqlalchemy module supposedly handles the engine and session "behind the curtain", so to speak.  Or at least that's what I've understood.  But I've obviously misunderstood something (or many things).

I also tried to explicitly commit the session.  It didn't throw any error on submit, but neither did it update the database.

**Summarizing the question**

How can I get my app (represented by the files below) to update the database without explicitly declaring the engine and session, which I think would be a significant departure from the approach in the Pocoo tutorial?

**By the way**

One incidental difference between my files below and those of the tutorial is that, whereas the tutorial uses blog posts as the fundamental record unit, I've changed it to projects.  But the two are analogous as far as data structure is concerned.

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.setdefault(
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI', '***Omitted for security***'
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    with app.app_context():
        from . import db
        db.init_app(app)

        from . import summary
        app.register_blueprint(summary.bp)
        app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='index')

    return app
```

**models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Date
from flaskr.db import get_db

db = get_db()

class projects(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    project = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    project_manager = db.Column(db.String(26), unique=False, nullable=True)
    business_benefits = db.Column(db.String(1024), unique=False, nullable=True)
```

**db.py**

```
import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = SQLAlchemy(current_app)
    return g.db

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

**summary.py**

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for, current_app
)

from flaskr.db import get_db

with current_app.app_context():
    from flaskr.models import projects

bp = Blueprint('summary', __name__)

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    project = projects.query.all()
    return render_template('summary/index.html', projects=project)

@bp.route('/<int:id>/update', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def update(id):
    db = get_db()
    project = projects.query.filter_by(project_id=id).first()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        project.project_name = request.form['project']
        project.business_benefits = request.form['business_benefits']
        error = None
        db.session.commit()

        if not project:
            error = 'Project name is required.'

        if error is not None:
            flash(error)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('summary.index', projects=project))

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('summary/update.html', post=project)
```

Comment: I'd start by making sure that the session used by the query attribute `projects.query` is the same session as `db.session`. `object_session(project) is db.session()` would be one way to check that (the brackets are there on purpose – `db.session` is a scoped session).

Comment: @IljaEverilä, I think you're on to something. The test confirmed that they are not the same session, as you suspected. Can you see what I've done to disassociate them? Although the update view calls the `get_db()` function again, my understanding from the Pocoo tutorial [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/database/) is that the `g` object stores and returns the same `.db` from the first time it was instantiated. Also, I thought that the following lines in `summary.py` kept the update associated with the session: `with current_app.app_context(): from flaskr.models import projects`

Comment: If my memory serves me right `g` is not as global as it might seem: "The data on g is lost after the context ends, and it is not an appropriate place to store data between requests." So it may be that when you construct your models they use their own instance of Flask-SQLAlchemy's `SQLAlchemy` object, commonly named `db`, and so the query properties have their own scoped session. All this is speculation on my part.